# box collider getting caught on tilemap collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics, collision, tilesets

I have a player that uses a box collier and a level that uses tilemap colliders.
The folowing code is drawing contact points with the wall:

```cs
    int numContacts = mBody.GetContacts(levelFilterGround, contactPoints);
    for (int i = 0; i < numContacts; i++)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(contactPoints[i].point, contactPoints[i].normal * 0.4f, Color.red, 0, false);
    }
```

*for these purposes levelFilterGround is set to no filter (it is a ContactFilter2D)

[image: player stuck on wall]

As you can see the player is "standing" on one of the individual "boxes" that make up the wall.
For reference here is the players collider and rigidbody:

[image: player's rigidbody]

[image: player's collider]

And the faulty tilemap collider:

[image: tile map collider]

I appoligise for my extensive use of images here and I know it is bad practice but I don't know how else to include this information, if anyone does please tell me.

Anyway, this is pretty problematic because a platformer where you can stand on and jump up walls isn't really a platformer.

*clarification, this issue doesn't always happen, only once every few jumps into the wall, it seems to happen more often with lower default contact offsets, but I might just be imagining it.

If anyone else has had and solved this problem please tell me what you did to fix it so that I can fix this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Composite Collider 2D. You can add it with the tilemap Collider, which will join all the individual collider boxes. change "OffsetDistance" if there is space between your collider boxes.

Comment: Don't forget to check Used  By Composite on the Tilemap Collider 2D.

Comment: Thank you this seems to be working, it requires a rigidbody2d but I just set it to kinematic and that was fine